# error Error: ENOENT, stat 'F:\Folder\development\web\$HOME\.node_modules_global'

Tags: node.js, git-bash, npm-install

I am really new to the node set up project and cureently facing issue while trying to run the proj.

I am getting this above error while running "npm install" on the node proj.
Either of the command : "npm" , "npm start" , "npm cache clean" gives me the above error.
I checked on links the solution given was to manually create a npm folder. But here i am getting $home.node_modules_global error.

I even tried creating those folders. but no use. Im continuing to get this error.

Can anyone help me fix this error. Im not able to move forward with the proj.
Please support.

Note : Is it something related to $HOME variable set up.. i havent created and environmental variable as such.

Comment: This problem is often related to file rights. Try checking permissions or running the command with sudo

Comment: I tried that no use. and sudo says  sudo command not found.! any other help?  I even changed the prmission of the files. Btw im using windows 8 OS.